# How Do I Give My Apache Server Access to Write to Files?

Tags: php, linux, apache, webserver, file-permissions

I am running an apache webserver on a virtual machine on my pc.  The vm is running zorin linux.  I have written a php script that writes some data to another text file in the same directory.  Both files are located in /var/www/html/.  I have already verified that the webserver user is www-data, and I have attempted to make that user owner of the /var/www/html directory, as well as everything within that directory.  Here is the command that I have used to do this:

```
sudoo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/*
```

I have also verified that the www-data user is the owner of this directory and it's contents using

```
ls -dl /var/www/html/
ls -dl /var/www/html/*
```

both return that the owner is www-data.
Even after doing all of this, the php file is still unable to write to the file correctly.  At this point I am stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `getenforce` return?

Comment: getenforce 
returns Disabled